# IOS DrEdit example for spreadsheets

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to use the DrEdit example from google to load and upload spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is possible.

Instead of uploading files of type `text/plain` upload your own files. They might be CSV or Excel files, making sure to pass `convert=True` parameter if you wish the files to be converted to Google Spreadsheet format.

When downloading Google Spreadsheets, you need to use the `exportLink` for the appropriate format you want the Google Spreadsheet exported as.

Comment: I'm trying to use the DrEdit example so i changed the mime type to text/csv and nothing happens.  Am I missing something else somewhere?

Comment: If you are converting the file, leave the mime type empty in the file resource.

Comment: So if i leave the file mime type empty, it will convert to google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code (from the DrEdit loadFileContent method) to download Google Drive Sheets to my app;

```
// Trying to access spreadsheet files using exportLinks metadata
    GTLDriveFileExportLinks *myExportLinks = self.driveFile.exportLinks;    
    NSString *spreadsheetURL = [[myExportLinks additionalProperties]objectForKey:@"text/csv"];
    NSLog(@"AND the WINNING URL is = %@", spreadsheetURL);   
    GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [self.driveService.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:spreadsheetURL];
```

The code works fine downloading files in CSV format into the DrEdit project.

When factored into my app though the fetch just stalls and doesn't complete the download.